# Updating Drupal modules via git on remote server

Tags: version-control

Here is my Drupal workflow for updating modules.

1. I update modules on my local dev and test.
2. Run update via drush if needed.
3. Commit and push to github.
4. Pull these new updates from Github on remote server to live site.
5. run update via drush.

However, I was thinking of making a "modules-update" branch, pushing to that from local dev, pulling that branch to my live site and merge with my master branch later if all went well. If all does not go well for some reason on the live site, then I could simply pull from my master branch that had the older versions and do a restore of the DB from the backup and restore module if need be.

So my questions is, I am looking for feedback if this seems like a sound practice or are there better ways to do this? I am fairly new to Git so I am guessing there might perhaps be a better way than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the workflow you mentioned look good. You just need to make sure you have a latest database backup in case you need to revert back. 
Have you looked into https://getpantheon.com/ it is free for drupal development. Request an invitation code at https://getpantheon.com/request-code Best thing about pantheon is it provides dev test and live sites, daily, weekly, monthly and on demand backups. Push code from dev to test and live, Pull database and files from live to test and dev with just push of a button.

Comment: Thanks, Pantheon looks really interesting. I will check it out though it seems like it's still in beta. I am also wondering what it will eventually cost.

Comment: As per the founder it will remain free for drupal development. At the moment it cost $100 per month to host a live site. They are working on $50 and $25 per month for smaller sites. It is more than ready for production sites. I have been using it for over a year. www.http://steinberg.us.com/  this is one of the live sites we are hosting on panthoen.

Comment: It would be interesting to see whether it's possible to develop locally, test on Pantheon, and then push the changes to a remote production server using git.

Comment: I think it is not possible to push from panthoen but one could log into production server and pull from panthoen.